# Why does my Lua.js script overwrite my CSV files?

Tags: csv, lua, ftp

I am logging certain objects from an energy system.
Herefore, I locally create CSV documents.
The problem is that every fifteen minutes when the script runs, it OVERwrites the data from the previous 15 minutes.
I would like it to create a CSV-file daily (WORKS)
writes all data from that day in it (ONLY THE LAST 15 MINUTES)

```
--require('socket.ftp')

-- ftp file
--ftpfile = string.format('ftp://ftplogin:ftppassword@192.168.1.11/%s.csv', os.date('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M'))
--local ftp gebruiken
ftpfile = string.format('/home/ftp/%s.csv', os.date('%Y-%m-%d'))
-- get past quarter data (3600 seconds)
logtime = os.time() - 15 * 60

-- list of objects by id
objects = {}

-- objects with logging enabled
query = 'SELECT address, datatype, name FROM objects WHERE disablelog=0'
for _, object in ipairs(db:getall(query)) do
  objects[ tonumber(object.address) ] = {
    datatype = tonumber(object.datatype),
    name = tostring(object.name or ''),
  }
end

-- csv buffer
buffer = { '"date","address","name","value"' }

-- get object logs
query = 'SELECT src, address, datahex, logtime, eventtype FROM objectlog WHERE logtime >= ? ORDER BY id DESC'
for _, row in ipairs(db:getall(query, logtime)) do
  object = objects[ tonumber(row.address) ]

  -- found matching object and event type is group write
  if object and row.eventtype == 'write' then
    datatype = object.datatype

    -- check that object datatype is set
    if datatype then
      -- decode data
      data = knxdatatype.decode(row.datahex, datatype)

      -- remove null chars from char/string datatype
      if datatype == dt.char or datatype == dt.string then
        data = data:gsub('%z+', '')
      -- date to DD.MM.YYYY
      elseif datatype == dt.date then
        data = string.format('%.2d.%.2d.%.2d', data.day, data.month, data.year)
      -- time to HH:MM:SS
      elseif datatype == dt.time then
        data = string.format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', data.hour, data.minute, data.second)
      end
    else
      data = ''
    end

    -- format csv row
    logdate = os.date('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S', row.logtime)
    csv = string.format('%q,%q,%q,%q', logdate, knxlib.decodega(row.address), object.name, tostring(data))

    -- add to buffer
    table.insert(buffer, csv)
  end
end

-- upload to ftp only when there's data in buffer
--if #buffer > 1 then
--  result, err = socket.ftp.put(ftpfile, table.concat(buffer, '\r\n'))
--end

-- error while uploading
--if err then
--  alert('FTP upload error: %s', tostring(err))
if #buffer > 1 then
  data = table.concat(buffer, '\r\n')
  io.writefile(ftpfile, data)
end
```

Comment: Please show the docs on the function `io.writefile()` you're using in the program.  It's not a standard Lua function.

Comment: You need to open file in "append" mode instead of the default "overwrite" mode.  Probably, your function has some options for it.

Comment: https://openrb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/lua-short-manual.pdf

Comment: I couldn't find any options to the function

Answer (score 0):

```lua
if #buffer > 1 then
    data = table.concat(buffer, '\r\n')
    local file = io.open(ftpfile, "ab")
    file:write(data)
    io.close(file)
    file = nil
end
```

`writefile` doesn't have the option for appending so you'll need to open a connection to the file in append mode, write to it and then close the connection as you can see above.

Comment: `io.open(ftpfile, "ab")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff What advantage does "ab" give? I had thought the options were only "a" and "a+"

Comment: `b` means binary (for windows)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Ah yeah, just in case there's non ASCII characters I presume.

Comment: I replaced the code by the code you wrote, It does nothing to my csv document. The latest update timestamp is still from when it wrote with the old code.

Comment: I get this error
User script:75: attempt to call method 'writefile' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 User script:75: in main chunk

Comment: Replace `file:writefile` with `file:write`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: 
Now it works
THANKS FOR THE HELP GUYS!! :D

```
if #buffer > 1 then
  --We maken de data compatibel om als string te writen in ons doc.
    data = table.concat(buffer, '\r\n')
  --Connectie leggen met het document , de "ab" wil zeggen dat er append zal worden gebruikt en geen overschrijving
    local file = io.open(ftpfile, "ab")
  --Schrijf de data naar het opgegeven pad
    io.writefile(ftpfile, data)
  --connectie stilleggen.
    io.close(file)
    file = nil
end
```